# Planes in ray tracing appearing too dark

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing

I have a problem with my ray tracer. I'm trying to render a [Cornell Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornell_box) with different objects inside, and when I create the box with spheres the result is fine, but when I create the box with planes the result is too dark, and seems to have much noise.

Results with planes:

[image: Results with planes]

Results with spheres:

[image: Results with spheres]

My Plane ray intersection seems to be just fine:

```
virtual bool hits(ray r, vec& h){
    double den=dot(normal_,r.direction());
    if (abs(den) > 0.0001f) // your favorite epsilon
    {
        double t=dot((point_-r.origin()),normal_)/den;
        if (t >= 0){
            h=vec(t,0.0,0.0);
            return true; // you might want to allow an epsilon here too
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Does someone have a clue what could be happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate the `planes` vs. `spheres`? The upper and lower image seems to show the identical scene. How do you create a _box with spheres_? Using spheres with infinite radius?

Comment: Yes, using spheres with infinity radius, but I realised what the problem was. I changed the occlusion by putting a new condition to avoid planes to hit themselves. This way, occlusion is avoided in case the ray comes from the same object that it hits. Also, by using some bias for the hitting point along the normal helps getting rid of this problem

Answer (score 1):

I realised what the problem was. I changed the occlusion by putting a new condition to avoid planes to hit themselves. This way, occlusion is avoided in case the ray comes from the same object that it hits. Also, by using some bias for the hitting point along the normal helps getting rid of this problem